# Jquery.load HTML and insert into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm kind of stuck at the moment. Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.
First time asking a question, so please bear with me :)

I have a main page with a few buttons. Each button opens a bootstrap modal. I am able to load dynamic content into the modal. Also inserting external HTML works, but here's the catch.... The HTML content I insert also has some 'fancy' features like my main page has (ex. animated progress bar/skills) For the external HTML to work I need to reference the same script as my main page has, but if so, things on my main page gets broken.

My question is, is there any way that I can insert HTML into my modal and have the inserted HTML be able to use the existing functions on my main page?

```js
var iModal = document.getElementById('iModal');
iModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function handler() {
  // Button that triggered the modal
  var button        = event.relatedTarget;
  var modalTitleArg = button.getAttribute('data-bs-title');
  var modalId       = button.getAttribute('data-bs-id');
  var modalTitle    = iModal.querySelector('.modal-title');
  var modalBody     = iModal.querySelector('.modal-body');

  modalTitle.textContent = modalTitleArg;
  if (modalId == 1) {
    $('.modal-body').load('Content1.html', function() {
      $.getScript("js/functions.js") //get script, modal works, broken mainpage.
    });
  } else if (modalId == 2) {
    $('.modal-body').load('Content2.html', function() {
      //$.getScript("js/functions.js") //script reference in html, modal works broken mainpage
    });
  } else {
    $('.modal-body').load('Content3.html', function() {
      //$.getScript("js/functions.js") // no script at all, broken modal, mainpage works fine
    });
  }

  this.removeEventListener('show.bs.modal', handler);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#iModal" data-bs-id="1" data-bs-title="Title1">Click me 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#iModal" data-bs-id="2" data-bs-title="Title2">Click me 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#iModal" data-bs-id="3" data-bs-title="Title3">Click me 3</button>

<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="iModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h3>
        <!-- data-bs-title -->
        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- external html content -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your "Content1.html", "Content2.html" etc. there is already an attached `<script src="js/functions.js"></script>` (as in a simple web page), then you can add content simply through an [iframe tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) (via the [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-src) attribute). Sample part of the code from your example:

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
  <iframe class="modal-body-frame"></iframe>
</div>
...
<script>
...
  const modalFrame = document.querySelector('.modal-body-frame');
  if (modalId === 1) modalFrame.src = 'Content1.html';
...
</script>
...
```

But if you need to embed the script into the content every time, then you can use the [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) attribute of the `iframe` tag. Example below:

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
  <iframe class="modal-body-frame" srcdoc=""></iframe>
</div>
...
<script>
...
const modalFrame = document.querySelector('.modal-body-frame');
if (modalId === 1) {
  $.get('Content1.html', function(data) {
    modalFrame.srcdoc = data.replace('</head>', '<script src="js/functions.js"></script></head>');    
  })
}
...
</script>
...
```

When using frame, it is important not to forget about [Feature Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy) and the ability to add permission via the [allow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy#the_iframe_allow_attribute) attribute (Example: `<iframe srcdoc="<p>Example test page</p>" allow="fullscreen"></iframe>`).

Comment: Ok, this was pretty helpful as I gathered more knowledge about everything. In the end I still ended up not using an iFrame, and just parsing the HTML with the jQuery.load. I solved my problem by using custom javascript for the modals instead of trying to use the framework. 
Thanks for your help!